# Mariadb: geography

Tags: geospatial, mariadb

I need to check if the distance between two geographic point is less then **N km**. I'm trying to execute this query:

```
select st_distance(
  ST_GeomFromText('point(45.764043 4.835658999999964)', 4326),
  ST_GeomFromText('point(45.750371 5.053963)', 4326)
) < :n
```

But it doesn't work because:

> So far the SRID property is just a dummy in MySQL, it is stored as part of a geometries meta data but all actual calculations ignore it and calculations are done assuming Euclidean (planar) geometry.

(https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/st_transform-missing/)

My goal is to convert this distance to the metric distance or to convert the **N** to the degrees.

How I can do it?
Maybe, you know a better solution?

P.S. I need a solution based on the spatial methods (or more better for the performance).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the "distance" function is available (yet) in `SPATIAL`.  There is a regular `FUNCTION` in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/latitudelongitude-indexing/ that does the work.  However, the args and output are scaled lat/lng (10000*degrees).  The code could be altered to avoid the scaling, but it is needed in the context of that blog page.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too hardcoded. Really, there are no solutions out of the box or in some extensions?

Comment: Oracle's MySQL 5.7.6 has `ST_Distance_Sphere()` and `ST_MakeEnvelope()`.  I don't know when MariaDB will add it.

Comment: As of Mariadb v10.2.38, ST_Distance_Sphere() has been available. Conveniently that's the exact version my shared hosting provider is using. I've not tried it yet, just looked at the docs.   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_distance_sphere/